# Match string NOT having two consecutive characters as digits in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to find/match string NOT containing two consecutive characters as digits.

For example, in the following strings:

12ab

1ab2

1a2b

ab12

I'd like to select the 2nd and 3rd strings - 1ab2 and 1a2b.

Have been trying to write a matcher regex for hours now :(

Your help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be something like

```
if ( ! myString.matches( ".*\\d\\d.*" ))
```

But if you want an actual regular expression, without the "not" logic outside, there's always

```
"\\D*(\\d\\D+)*\\d?"
```

This matches any number of "digit" characters (`\d`), provided each one is followed by one or more "non-digit" characters (`\D`) before the next digit.  There can be optionally some non-digits at the beginning, and optionally one more digit at the end.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I'm looking how to use the negation inside the regex :(

Comment: Lovely, it worked. Thank you v much! Mind explaining the regex?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
"^((?!\\d{2}).)*$"

"11ab2".matches("^((?!\\d{2}).)*$"); // false
"1pab2".matches("^((?!\\d{2}).)*$"); // true
"1pa52".matches("^((?!\\d{2}).)*$"); // false
```

`(?!\\d{2}).` means match a character if it is not followed by 2 digits.

Comment: @CyrilleKa I tried it on [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it's behaving correctly.  (Shoulda done that on my own answer first. :()

Comment: To clarify a bit: `(?!\\d{2}).` means match a character if it is not the first of a 2-digit sequence.  That's a little different than how you worded it; if the source is `"11"`, there is no character _followed_ by two digits, but the pattern correctly rejects the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regex that matches if there are no two consecutive digits (as opposed to writing a matcher that matches if there are two consecutive digits and then using `!`), there are a couple possibilities, at least:

(1) Negative lookahead:

```
if (myString.matches ("^(?!.*\\d\\d).*"))
```

You're telling the matcher, "Please match if you can find the beginning of the string not followed by a pattern of any character sequence followed by two digits".

(2) Brute force:

```
if (myString.matches ("\\D*(\\d\\D+)*\\d?"))
```

`\\D` matches anything that isn't a digit.  This is set up so that any digit that appears in the source must be followed by a non-digit or by the end of the string.

EDIT: the previous version had `^` and `$`, which are necessary if you're using `find` but not if you're using `matches`.

Comment: @kartz Because you were using `matches` and it's required to match the whole string, which I missed.  I've fixed it by adding `.*` which will match everything once the lookahead doesn't fail.